# Accessing a "Page Field" value in layout.cshtml

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have added a field (media picker field) for "BackgroundPhoto" to the Page content type.

I'm trying to get the page so when that field exists, or has a value, that it's added through css as the background URL to the layout-wrapper found in layout.cshtml.

I have searched and come close to finding how this works, but never accessing a value from a content type on the layout page.  Does anyone have an example where this works? Specifically, a value in a page field is added to the "layout-wrapper" item in layout.cshtml.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the layout wrapper is document.cshtml. You could override that to render a value that you stored in HttpContext from your deeper field template.
To recap: create a template override for your field in your theme; from there, set the value of the field into a HttpContext item; From document.cshtml, retrieve and render that value.